# How to redirect all request to specific ip address in ubuntu

Tags: linux, forwarding

How to redirect all request to specific ip address in linux I have tried following command but its not working

```
  sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:80

  sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:443
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use :

```
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```